# PHP Form Validation Script Not Loading

Tags: php, forms, validation

In my PHP class, I have an assignment and one of the requirements is to build a form and perform validation on it. I can't seem to figure out why my form validation script is not being loaded when I click submit.

[signup_block.php](http://pastebin.com/3LSX1ZNQ)

[validate.php](http://pastebin.com/7UpFxAQm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a input of type [submit](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.submit.html):

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Instead of:

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I feel stupid now.